Desktop won't post after failed BIOS update
I have an EVGA Z97 Classified Motherboard (EVGA 152-HR-E979). I tried flashing the BIOS using this link: https://www.evga.com/support/download/showdlinfo.aspx?id=15467&type=N&acctype=BIOS&accversion=2.06&part_number=152-HR-E979. Upon running the update.bat, the command prompt continued to do its thing but after a little bit it gave me an error of some sort. After pressing enter to continue, the desktop immediately restarted. Now, I am stuck with no POST or boot signal, with two beeps. It first shows error code 36 before beeping, and then while beeping it displays F2. I have tried resetting CMOS (pressing internal and external buttons and removing the battery) and removing RAM sticks individually. Is my motherboard fried? I appreciate any support.


Now, I am stuck with no POST or boot signal, with two beeps. It first shows error code 36 before beeping, and then while beeping it displays F2. I have tried resetting CMOS (pressing internal and external buttons and removing the battery) and removing RAM sticks individually. Is my motherboard fried?

Your primary BIOS is corrupt. Fall to the secondary or trinary BIOS on your board

